# Active directory domain owned externally by third party

Tags: active-directory, domain-name

I've inherited a network where the .com domain name used by active directory internally is owned by a completely unrelated third party externally (Along the lines of `companyint.com`).

This AD domain name differs from the domain name used for the company  website (`company.com` and not `companyint.com`) and isn't published externally but had been used to host adult content & been related to malicious content in the past. Currently it seems to be something benign.

We've attempted to purchase this domain but so far it hasn't gone any where.

Are there any risks with leaving this setup as is? I've not encountered a situation like this before and didn't want to risk leaving any potential issues open for exploitation.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding. Are the names the same or aren't they? `company.com` and `companyint.com` are completely different names. `microsoft.com` and `microsoftint.com` are not the same domain name and have no relation one to the other.

Comment: He's saying (as I understand it) that `company.com` is their actual public domain name, while `companyint.com` is their internal AD domain name... but it's *also* a public name they don't own.

Comment: That's it. The AD domain name that is used isn't owned by and is active on the internet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, this means you can't resolve DNS names for the external domain from inside your network, because your AD DNS servers will assume (correctly) they are authoritative for that zone, and so they will never query the public DNS servers which actually manage that domain; if you need to resolve names such as `www.companyint.com` from your internal network, you'll have to manually create those DNS records in your internal DNS zone. This also applies to sending email to recipients @ that domain, which is based on `MX` records and thus is affected by the same issue.

There should instead not be any issue *outside* your network: the domain will behave correctly for everyone which is not using your AD DNS servers for name resolution; the only scenario in which issues could arise is in providing VPN access to your network: in this case, name resolution on external client systems which are also connected to your network via VPN could get quite messy.

You should really strive to fix this, either by buying the external domain or by renaming your internal AD one.